# How to do debug Memory Leaks and do thread profiling in app built using Rails 4.2.1 + Nginx + Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, memory-leaks

I have an app that is built using Ruby on Rails and Nginx along with open source version of Phusion Passenger. I want to learn how to do take Memory Dumps and track Object Allocation / Garbage Collection and analyze it ? 
Along with this I want to track how many threads are being created at any point of time in the application and if later I switch to Enterprise version of Phusion Passenger then what kind of performance improvements I can expect to get.

Ideally would like step by step instructions on solving the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracking memory usage, try those tools :

https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler
https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks

Comment: will try it out and update if this suits my needs or not in a couple of days.